# PHP Repost Using Client SSL Certs

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am working with a site that builds XML files that are then posted to a RESTful interface. I have built the tool to generate the files and I would like to upload them to the RESTful interface. I am having a slight problem. It would be nice to POST the file using a form, but the "content-type" must be "application/xml" not "multipart/form-data", so that ruled out posting that way. Next, I figured I'd try to cURL the file, but that failed, too.

The RESTful interface requires the user's certificate in order to process data. That's because the interface keeps track of who is uploading based on their cert information. So, I was hoping to get help with one of two options

1) Post the data, and client certificates that are in the browser, to the RESTful interface using cURL

2) Process the data, set the headers properly and then somehow redirect the POST using the client's browser to the page. I know the page will authenticate a user if they go to the RESTful URL. So if I could somehow setup the page data as an "application/xml" and then tell the user's browser "Hey, redirect to this address and send this data"...

Suggestions?

Comment: Well, use the client-certificate and you're fine. What is your question? - And as you might imagine for certified requests, there is no foolish "Hey go there server, it's more safe over there but has no certificate I tell you" feauture.

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how to forward the php request to the other server...we do back-end processing of the upload, and in order to use the client cert, we'd have to post that data to the restful interface through the user's browser...unless there's a way to use my app as a proxy (somehow).